# Adjust daylight savings in LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, time, timezone

Is there a way to make LXDE adjust the clock for daylight savings? It doesn't have to be done automatically, I can "click the button myself" but just not tamper with the value of the clock itself. ...automatic would be preferable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Menu->System Tools->Time and Date.  The Unlock the settings page.  Change your Time zone to where you are located and select Keep synchronized with internet servers and close.  That should allow the automatic change to daylight savings time.

Comment: I can't find time and date in the system tools menu...